# Real-time notification using Python

Tags: dojo, websocket, comet, flask, tornado

First there is [TornadoWeb](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), it's async and non-blocking, and on the other side: there is [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/). If I use tornado, how can I communicate with dojo?

And the other problem, if I use a WSGI solution like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), can I make a "notification" with them? Or dojo must have an "open connection" to speak with the server, which is not done using WSGI? mean; Apache or CherryPy will not work with Dojo?

And if WSGI can't speak with Dojo, what about using Atom or Feeds to program notifications under WSGI?

NB: the notification will be devided on two: notification about products for all users, and notification about specific users; it will use sessions...

And last question, what about WebSockets and HTML5? the server must be compatible to use this option with the browser?

Comment: http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/websocket.html + http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/dojo-websocket should give you some hints...

Comment: Well, the server sends messages, the client receives them, and vice versa... so yes !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why Dojo seems to be the problem in the communication.

Dojo provides you with AJAX wrappers which you can use for almost real-time notifications in a web app with little load by making an AJAX request each 1-5 seconds.

If the app will have a lot of users, frequent AJAX requests can cause too much overhead quickly. Fortunately, you don't have to use Dojo to communicate with the server. You could have a look at [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) and, if you want to stick to Python on the server-side, [gevent-socketio](https://bitbucket.org/Jeffrey/gevent-socketio). It uses the best technology available in the web browser (WebSockets, Flash sockets, comet) to provide real-time communication.

There is also `dojox.socket` but I think it's less robust (and far less popular).

You should remember, however, that by using any kind of persistent connection (be it WebSockets, Socket.IO or dojox.socket) you need an asynchronous server able to maintain many simultaneous connections.

The solution you choose should depend on the web app itself and its user base.

Comment: but how about tornado, isent a solution for python?

Comment: It is. In fact, you can use either Tornado or gevent to write an asynchronous server. I've just found out that there's a [Socket.IO implementation for Tornado](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio2) too. If you know Tornado, go for it. If not, then [some benchmarks](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers) indicate that gevent might perform better (this is quite an old benchmark though and doesn't consider WebSockets performance).

Comment: yes, but Tornado is also a framework, so it has a Template engine and goog URL dispatcher like the one used by web.py

Comment: If you plan to build the whole web app in it, then you have a point. If you just want to write a Socket.IO server, then those things won't matter.

Comment: so mixing wsgi and tornado will work if only the non blocking is in notifications?

Comment: You can run [Tornado through WSGI](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/wsgi.html) or have two separate applications, one written in some traditional WSGI framework (e.g. Flask) and other in Torando or gevent. In the second case, you will have to provide some simple way of communication between those two apps if you have user sessions (e.g. passing an user ID signed with HMAC).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8247457/903921
i've mixed the both application (wsgi and non blocking) but now i'm looking how to let the both know the cookies of each other (session), what about this tip that you provided? (using HMAC)