# Flask render a word cloud

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I am trying to render a wordcloud that I can run on my computer w/o flask.

I am using [this question as a base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107414/passing-a-matplotlib-figure-to-html-flask?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

## Route

```
@app.route('/wordcloud/<vendor_duns>')
def images(vendor_duns):
    words = Words.query.filter(Words.vendor_duns == vendor_duns).with_entities(Words.words).all()
    # t = [r.__dict__ for r in words]
    # print(t)
    one_row = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(words))
    text = ' '.join(one_row)
    return render_template("wordcloud.html", text=text)


@app.route('/fig/<vendor_duns>')
def fig(vendor_duns):
    # TODO add test model and query
    words = Words.query.filter(Words.vendor_duns == vendor_duns).with_entities(Words.words).all()
    one_row = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(words))
    text = ' '.join(one_row)
    wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
    plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
    plt.axis("off")
    img = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(img)
    img.seek(0)
    return send_file(img, mimetype='image/png')
```

## Template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Wordcloud{% endblock %}
{% block content %}  
{{text}}
    <div>
      <img src="{{ url_for('sam.fig', vendor_duns=vendor_duns) }}" alt="Image Placeholder" height="100">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

First off the `{{text}}` in the template is just for view.  If I nav to a specific vendor_duns I will get a long string of text, but no image.

So two questions, where exactly do I need to run the query? in the `fig` or image `function`.

The second question, I get a blank image, so I am not sure exactly how to write the wordcloud to a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

wordcloud `to_image` method creates a PIL object so all you have to do is just call the PIL's `save` method.

```
img = BytesIO()
wordcloud.to_image().save(img, 'PNG')
img.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can plot wordcloud in flask app using BytesIO(), wordcloud and render it in html page.

```
@app.route("/<xyz>")
def profile():
  wordcloud = WordCloud(collocations=True, background_color= "white" ).generate(text)

  wordcloudImage = wordcloud.to_image()
  img = BytesIO()
  wordcloudImage.save(img, format='PNG')
 imgword='data:image/png;base64,}'.format(base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode())
return render_template('visuals.html', wordcloud = imgword)
```

#in html file put

```
<div class="img" align="center">
        <img src="{{ wordcloud }}" alt="wordcloud">
    </div>
```