# tornado flask close wait

Tags: python, flask, tornado

when i make a web application use **torado+flask** ,i meet a question that when i send a request to my application,it response nothing to me ,and its always await.
  when i find the problem,i found that there is many **'close wait'** in my server machine(linux).
  i don't know how to resolve this question,can anybody help me?
  here is the code i use tornado:

```
#coding=utf-8
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer`enter code here`
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from service import app #app is a flask in another file:app=Flask(__name__)
from config import SERVER_CONF
from appLog import logging


def startService():
    logging.info('start web,http://%s:%s/test'%(SERVER_CONF['IP'],SERVER_CONF['PORT']))
    try:
        http_server=HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
        http_server.listen(SERVER_CONF['PORT'],address=SERVER_CONF['IP'])
        IOLoop.instance().start()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('start failed:')
        logging.error(e)


if __name__=='__main__':
    startService()
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need to use `FallbackHandler`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143141/using-flask-and-tornado-together/8247457#8247457).

That being said, I would strongly recommend against using this approach -- Tornado includes an excellent [microframework of its own](http://tornado.readthedocs.io/en/stable/webframework.html), which integrates much better with the server and is in many ways superior to Flask. If using Flask is important I would recommend exploring a different ways to ensure concurrency (e.g. multiple instances behind a nginx load balancer), or even taking a look at [Sanic](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic), which is both asynchronous and very similar to Flask.

Comment: `FallbackHandler` is unnecessary unless you want to *combine* a wsgi/flask app with a native tornado one. But you're right that running flask in a Tornado WSGIContainer is generally a bad idea: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer. If you're using flask you should probably use gunicorn or uwsgi instead of tornado's http server.

Comment: Absolutely -- in my answer I just assumed that you should wrap Flask in a WSGI container for production.

Comment: Thanks all your answers. I'll consider use the gunicorn instead of tornado's http server.Thank you!